# Distribution plot with box plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, metrics

I'm trying to plot the distribution of a box plot point with Python Matplotlib, but I can't find some similiar examples. Someone can help me? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Did you generate that image yourself? Do you have any code?

Comment: No, this image is from an article. I only have a latex code for this.